# How do I change a single quote of an array.element (that is inside an object) into a double quote without creating a new array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, replace

I was told to try and use a certain code for one of the problems I solved a while ago. I'm trying to figure it out but am coming up with nada.
Using replace(), map() etc..
This is all supposed to be done using replit and not changing the whole array as part of the 'For Fun' challenge.

```js
const products = [
  {
    priceInCents: 3995,
  },
  {
    priceInCents: 2500,
  },
  {
    priceInCents: 8900,
  },
  {
    priceInCents: 12500,
  },
];

/* Now trying to use:
products[i].priceInDollars = $${(products[i].priceInCents * .01).toFixed(2)}
*/

/*
  New 
    Code
        */


function addPriceInDollarsKeyToProducts(pricey)
{ for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++)  
    { for (let product = products[i];
      product.priceInDollars = `$${(product.priceInCents * .01).toFixed(2)}`; )
      
      break;
    } 
    
}

addPriceInDollarsKeyToProducts();
console.log(products)
```

Running this snippet btw makes it seem like it's okay.

For example: I want products[0].priceInDollars to be `"$39.95",`
but instead I get `'$39.95',`
Snippet runs it as `"$39.95"`

I'm not supposed to recreate the whole entire array.

If the code doesn't match the double quote requirements I get `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

*edited for clarification purposes*

Comment: You explicitly put quotes and a comma in the `priceInDollars` string, not sure what you expected. Unrelated, but I'd *really* recommend pretty much any other `{` pattern than this one.

Comment: I tried it without the double quotes at first and it just would return it as `'$39.95,'` I then tried various forms of replace( ) but it stays `'$39.95',` .
This is just the closest I can get to `"$39.95", ` .

Can you expand on your using any other `{ pattern ` ?

Comment: Let's start a step earlier, there aren't even single quotes in your data, what are you trying to replace....?

Comment: Are you maybe mistaking the devtools console's representation (which tries to resemble JS syntax you'd use) for actual data contained in the elements?

Comment: Say I remove the replace( ) from my code altogether, got rid of unnecessary console.log( ) 's and what not.

`function addPriceInDollarsKeyToProducts(pricey)
{ for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++)  
    { for (let product = products[i];
      product.priceInDollars =`"$${(product.priceInCents * .01).toFixed(2)}",`; )
      break;
    } 
    
}
addPriceInDollarsKeyToProducts();
console.log(products)`

The output would still be `'"$39.95",'`

Comment: @BananaMan the error may lie in the fact that the string you use to set `roduct.priceInDollars =` contains `"`, which is then printed when you log them. Anyway, you should synthetize your problem by only showing the tiny bit that fails. We'll better be able to understand what the issue is. Check the [mcve] documentation :)

Comment: Without the `"` the string produced is `'$39.95'` but I require it to be `"$39.95"` .  Because of this discrepancy my code would in turn produce `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` 

This is a complex topic that I tried to use snippet to produce an explanation for by adding console.log( ) since it's using single quotes, double quotes, and backticks throughout.

Comment: I simplified it, sorry, I overcomplicate things, even my questions lol

Answer (score 0):

Alright, a friend caught the problem.
I never reinserted my return like a dumb dumb.
Here I was going crazy trying to make a `'"$39.95"'` into a `"$39.95"` via replace(), map(), creating a replace function and what not when it was simply that I needed to add

`return products;`

at the end between the ending `}`